# async/await nodejs

Tags: javascript

Решил попробовать async/await, но столкнулся с проблемой:

```
router.get('/api/bookmarks-theme/', async function a (req, res, next) {
                                    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Метод в роуте:

```
router.get('/api/bookmarks-theme/', async function a (req, res, next) {

  BookmarkTheme.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

В чем проблема ?

Comment: попробуй обычную функцию а не стрелочную

Comment: router.get('/api/bookmarks-theme/', async function a (req, res, next) => {
                                                        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Ну так зачем там `=>`?

Comment: убрал, тоже самое

Comment: добавь обновленный код в вопрос с указание ошибки

Comment: ага, похоже асинк тут функция, попробуй `async(function a (req, res, next) {...})`

Comment: пишет TypeError: async is not a function

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44784/discussion-between-grundy-and-khotey-vitaliy).